# Can I log simulated instrument time in a simulator as a CFII?

Tags: flight-training, logging, flight-simulator

I started working as a flight instructor and have a couple of questions about logging sim time as a CFII:

1. If I fly a sim session with my student can I log the sim time as dual-given time?
2. If the sim session was conducted in simulated IMC, can I also log that for myself as simulated instrument time? Or does it only count for the student?

Comment: Why What do you put a hood or foggles on in a Sim when it can simulate IMC already?

Comment: Logging sim time as an instructor has no value for additional certificates, ratings or currency reasons.

Comment: Somewhat related https://www.reddit.com/r/flying/comments/7rex51/why_arent_their_sims_in_busy_metropolitan_areas/dswej7y/

Comment: You can log anything you want, whether or not it counts towards something is entirely different. See [Logging time in a simulator](https://landing.redbirdflight.com/posts/logging-time-in-a-simulator). It says as a CFI you can log it, however you should log it separately from other training (or make it clear in the entry) that you are using an ATD.

Comment: [Closely related](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/q/45146/62), maybe a dupe?

Comment: Please specify what jurisdiction you are asking for

Answer (score 1):

A Level C or D Full Flight Simulator (FFS) can be used for all training required for an initial type rating, a 61.58 check, an IPC, landings required to maintain landing and instrument currency. In fact, so long as it is not (in most cases) your first type rating, you can fly a Level C or D sim, get certified and then walk out to the airplane, load it up with PAX and go flying, legally while having ZERO actual flight time in the actual aircraft.

So I would say yes you can log Dual given in a flight simulator, but you cannot log that time as flight time.

Comment: Level D is zero flying time, Level C is not.

Comment: That is not correct @Koyovis. We have a Level C sim and there is ZERO flying time required to fly the actual aircraft unless you do not meet the 61.64 requirements (same as Level D). This is true for all Level C simulators certified under Part 60 in the US.

Comment: Yes indeed, Level C has zero flying time for what it is certified for. But it is not certified for all of the curriculum, if it was it would be a Level D.

Comment: Once again, incorrect @Koyovis. Level C and D have nothing to with the curriculum. We can do absolutely everything in the Level C that we can do in the Level D. The primary differences are 1) Visual Systems, 2) Motion Systems and 3) Audio Systems. Level D is a more high fidelity version of the two. We use the identical curriculum in both sims. This is based on the US FAA part 60 standards, I am not sure about other countries.

Comment: Why don't you check FAA 14CFR 60, requirements for Full Flight Simulators, Appendix A. In a Level C you cannot train for situations that are not modeled. Requirements applicable to Level D only:
2.k. The aerodynamic modeling in the simulator must include:
(1) Low-altitude level-flight ground effect;
(2) Mach effect at high altitude;
(3) Normal and reverse dynamic thrust effect on control surfaces; (4) Aeroelastic representations; and (5) Nonlinearities due to sideslip.

Comment: 5.f. The simulator must provide characteristic motion vibrations that result from operation of the airplane if the vibration marks an event or airplane state that can be sensed in the flight deck.
7.d. The simulator must provide realistic amplitude and frequency of flight deck noises and sounds. Simulator performance must be recorded, compared to amplitude and frequency of the same sounds recorded in the airplane, and be made a part of the QTG.

Comment: @Koyovis - We operate a part 142 school utilizing Level C and Level D simulators and have for the last 12 years. Every certification that we can do in our Level D simulator we do in our Level C simulators. This includes Initial Type Ratings, ATPs, 61.58s, 135.293/297 rides, etc. Flight Safety, SimCom and SimuFlight all have Level C simulators that they do complete initials in as well. I am not sure where you are getting your information, but it is incorrect. Call your local FSDO and ask them, or better yet, call FSI and ask about a CE500 initial in Long Beach in their Level C sim!

Comment: @Koyovis - My apologies - You are correct in that if a Level C simulator is built to the very basic standards of Part 60, it would not meet the requirements for a full type rating, they could do 80% in the sim, the rest in an aircraft. However, most of the Level C sims under the control of the NSP meet all the necessary standards to do everything in the sim. We have a Level C sim certified Level C but approved by the NSP to do 100% rides and we were certified under the (then) new Part 60 standards. The sim is NOT a Level D and we CAN do full certifications with no aircraft time necessary.

Comment: @ Richard interesting, what aircraft type is it?

Comment: @koyovis - It is a CJ1. List of all FAA certified sim are [here](https://www.faa.gov/about/initiatives/nsp/train_devices/media/All_FSTD.xlsx)